# Unmet dependencies/ Broken packages

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install the necessary plug-ins to play a video but I always get the "broken packages" message.

After searching on Ask Ubuntu I've already performed the `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get update` commands, but they won't work and when using `sudo apt-get -f install`, this is what I get:

```
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/67.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 179332 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libdjvulibre-text 3.5.24-9 (using .../libdjvulibre-text_3.5.24-9ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libdjvulibre-text ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libdjvulibre-text_3.5.24-9ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/share/djvu/osi/en/messages.xml.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/share/djvu/osi/en/messages.xml'): Input/output error
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdjvulibre-text_3.5.24-9ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

any help?

Comment: how do I make the backup? I can't install anything since I get the same message

Answer (score 1):

Check your sources file to make sure you haven't added anything that is illegitimate. To edit your sources:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

if you perfer `nano`. You can use this website to generate your sources file if you want, I've used it before:

- http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Once you are sure your sources file is good, then run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

That will update all of your software sources. Now upgrade your system:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you are still getting broken dependencies, then you are probably trying to install a package that needs another package that isn't in your repositories.